# Distributing Netlogo commands using Hubnet Client?

Tags: netlogo, hubnet

Is there a way to allow for clients to run commands with hubnet?

I see a tag in a button, for example, which can send a message, but can the client dedicate some computational power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The regular HubNet client doesn't do that; it's a thin client only.

It is possible to write your own custom HubNet client, that does anything you want; the server doesn't know the difference as long as the client sends the right messages. But you'd need to build such a client yourself. There's a repository on this theme at https://github.com/NetLogo/HubNetClients , but I see it hasn't been updated since 2011, so it might need tweaking to be usable in 2016.

Comment: Great!. This is useful since it has multiple examples in multiple languages. They're pretty easy to understand as well.